# Should List(Get) and Search be the same endpoint API (method)?

Tags: api, api-design, methods

Here are two endpoints (*or methods*):

- **ListResources(user_id)** - Fetch the resources based on the given user id.
- **SearchResources(query_options)** - Fetch the resources with specified conditions.

The `query_options` looks like this:

```
{
    user_id      : "", // the resource owner id
    keyword      : "", // the resource name which contains the keyword
    created_after: ""  // ...
}
```

I can call `SearchResources` with a specified `user_id` to get the same result as what `ListResources(user_id)` gives.

Since both the methods have the same behaviour, should I just merge two endpoints into one? Maybe a `ListResources` with `query_options`? Will there be any problem?

Answer (score 2):

As you used the term *endpoint* in the subject of the question, I assume you are  using (web) URI to define the location and identify of your (REST) resource.
Merging two methods into one based on the query parameters should not be the reason for your decisions. You should be defining your API based on your resources. 
The methods that implement functionality for resources could be one or more.

That said, in my opinion, the behaviour of the two methods is not the same. Listing a resource based on identity, essentialy returns a single resource instance.
However multiple resource instances could be matched with the `keyword` and similarly multiple resource instances could be retreived after the creation date.

The client of the API does not care how the service implements the functionality. It can be a single method or multiple method defined on the same resource e.g. for a resource `Customer`

```
GET http://domain.com/customers?id=25         // get a customer with id 25
GET http://domain.com/customers?keyword=male  // get a customer with keyword male
GET http://domain.com/customers?created_after=20191121  // get a customer created after
```

can either be implemented by service as

```java
public Response getCustomerById(int id) { /* code */}
public Response getCustomersByKeyword(String keyword) {/* code */}
public Response getCustomersCreatedAfter(String creationDate) { /* code */}
```

or ...

```java
public Response getCustomer(int id, String keyword, String creationDate) {
   if (id > 0) {
      // return get customer with id
   }
   if (keyword != null) {
      // return get customer with keyword
   }
   if (creationDate != null) {
      // return get customer after creation date
   }
   // or any possible combination
}
```

As the developer of the API you are free to chose. You need to decide what kind of granularity do you want to implement.